# Best programming language for fast DB reads and fast local data structure manipulation

Tags: database

I have a mysql database with a variety of different tables with some storing 100k+ rows. I wanted a language that would allow me to read quickly from the database, allowing me to collate data from various different tables and store them into local objects/data structures. I would then do most of the complex processing locally, which I would also like to be optimized for.

This is mainly for an analysis project of data that is cleared out every day. Some friends recommended Ruby or Python, but not knowing either, I wanted a second opinion before I took the leap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem here is the latency between the db and your application-tier code. Ping the DB server from where you intend to query the database from. Double that and that's your turnaround time for every operation. If you can live with that time, then you're OK. But you might be better off writing your manipulations in sprocs or something that lives close to the DB and use your application code to make that presentable to a user.

Answer (score 1):

100,000 records really isn't that much.  Provided you have enough ram and a multiple local "indexes" into the data are referencing the same objects and not copies, you'll be able to cache it locally and access it very quickly without concern.  While Ruby and Python are both interpreted languages and operation-for-operation slower than compiled languages, the reality is in executing an application only a small portion of cpu time is spent in your code and the majority is spent into the built-in libraries you call into, which are often native implementations, and thus are as fast as compiled code.

Either Ruby or Python would work fine for this and even if you find, after testing, that you performance is in fact not sufficient, translating from one of these to a faster language like Java or .NET or even C++ would be significantly faster than actually rewriting from scratch since you've really already done the tough work.

One other option is to cache all the data in an in-memory database.  Depending on how dynamic the analysis you need to do, this may work well in your situation.  SQLite works very well for this.

Also note that since you're asking about caching the data locally and then acting on the local cache only, the performance calling out to the database doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

the Db is going to be the bottle neck in most cases in terms of getting data out.

Really depends on what your "complex processing" is that will make the greatest difference in what language and what performance you need.

in terms of being easy to get up and started with, python and ruby are quick to get started with and get something working.   Bit slower compared to others for computing stuff.  But even then, both can compute a hell of a lot of stuff before you will notice much difference from a native compiler language.

Comment: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/mysql:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    matlab -nodesktop
    mex -I/usr/include/mysql -L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient mysql.cpp